# A simple problem with for loop

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list; I have the following program. It will check the list of numbers in the first column. If some numbers are missing by giving a step size. It will add the missing number with a "Nulls" in the second and third column respectively.

```
Nullloop[data_, start_, stop_, step_] :=
   Module[{i, j, collect = {}, m, n, o}, finnal = {};
       For[{i = start, j = 1},
           i <= stop,
           { m = data[[j, {1, 2, 3}]],
             n = data[[j, 1]], 
             o = {i, Null, Null}, 
             If[n ==  i, 
               collect = Append[collect, m], 
               collect = Append[collect, o]
               ],
             i = i + step,
             j = j + 1, 
             Clear[n, o, m]
           }]; 
           finnal = collect];
```

Then I run the following program

```
data1 = {{0, 1, 2}, {0.1, 4, 5}, {0.4, 3, 1}, 
         {0.6, 10, 2}, {0.7, 4,10}};
Nullloop[data1, 0.0, 0.7, 0.1]
```

But it gives the following

> {{0.0,1,2},{0.1,4,5},{0.2,Null,Null},{0.3,Null,Null}}

Then it stopped with some error,

> Part::partw: Part 6 of {{0,1,2},{0.1,4,5},{0.4,3,1},{0.6,10,2},{0.7,4,10}} does not exist. >>

what I want is the following

> ```
> {{0.0,1,2},{0.1,4,5},{0.2,Null,Null},
>
> {0.3,Null,Null},{0.4, 3, 1},{0.5,Null,Null}, 
>
> {0.6, 10, 2}, {0.7, 4,10}}
> ```

Comment: It stopped because you are testing `i <= stop` in the loop and since you called `Nullloop[data1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1]` then `stop == 0.3`...?

Comment: Also note that `For` loops and `Append`/`AppendTo` are typically discouraged in _Mathematica_. Try to use `Map`, `Table`, or similar, or if you have to loop explicitly, use `Do` and `Reap/Sow` to collect results.

Comment: See [alternatives to loops...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

Comment: Hi sorry for that, I mean even if you put Nullloop[data1,0.0,0.7,0.1]. It gives the error. I have edited my question. Sorry that I did not notice that it was 0.3 while I was writing this question. It is my fault and I apologize.

Comment: instead of just saying "some error" you should include the actual error (see edit). Clearly there is a flaw in your logic causing `j` to go beyond the length of data.  (indeed moving the `j=j+1` inside the `If` fixes it, but as said `For` loops are never a good way to go)

Comment: Hi George, Thank you very much. Could you explained the problem with for loop again, I did not get you there . You said if I j=j+1 inside "IF" will fix the error. How does it matter much if I put inside or outside IF loop. May I also know the flaw in my logic because as far as i<= stop, the value of j is also limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to achieve that result.

```
Function[{i}, 
  If[Length@# == 1, #[[1]], {i, Null, Null}] &@ 
   Select[data1, #[[1]] == i &]] /@ Range[0, .7, .1]

Sort@Join[data1, {#, Null, Null} & /@ 
     Complement[Range[0, .7, .1],data1[[All, 1]], 
        SameTest -> (Chop[#1 - #2] == 0 &)]]
```

> {{0, 1, 2}, {0.1, 4, 5}, {0.2, Null, Null}, {0.3, Null, Null}, {0.4, 
>     3, 1}, {0.5, Null, Null}, {0.6, 10, 2}, {0.7, 4, 10}}

note the second case illustrates another issue: you can not count on equality of floating point numbers.

Comment: Hi george2079, I have one more question. Could you please give a brief introduction of this special symbols "#","@#","@","&@" etc...

Comment: The link does not exist

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html